# Arduino Nano BLE 33 Sense receives but not able to transmit data to XBEE Pro S2C

Tags: serial, xbee, arduino-nano-ble

This is my first time asking a question so I will try my best to be precise and detailed.

I had recently started to work on a project that requires me to establish a wireless communication between two XBEE Pro S2C modules for the purpose of sending data of the sensors present on the Arduino Nano BLE 33 Sense.

**What I did so far:**
One of the XBEE (XBEE 1) is connected to my laptop using one of the USB-port, and the other (XBEE 2) to Arduino. The Arduino is also connected to the same laptop using another one of the USB ports. Using the [XBEE](https://microcontrollerslab.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/XBee-S2C-RF-Module-Pin-Configuration-diagram.jpg) and [Arduino](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358818914/figure/fig1/AS:1133123140104194@1647169017785/Arduino-33-Nano-BLE-Sense-pinout.ppm) pinout diagrams, I connected Vcc, Dout, Din and GND of XBEE 2 to 3.3V, D3, D4 and GND pins of the Arduino respectively. Both the XBEES have been configured using XCTU software and are operating in AT mode. The XBEES are able to talk to each other on the XCTU console if I directly plug both of them into the laptop using the USB ports.

To check and establish a serial communication between the XBEE 2 and Arduino, I wrote the following sketch on Arduino IDE and uploaded it:

```
int received = 0;
#include<HardwareSerial.h>
UART mySerial(digitalPinToPinName(4), digitalPinToPinName(3), NC, NC);
void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while(mySerial.available())
  {
    received =mySerial.read();
    if(received == 'a')
    {
      Serial.println("Character Received");
    }
  }   
}
```

Now, when I type the character 'a' in the XCTU console of XBEE 1, the XBEE 2 is able to receive it wirelessly and Arduino prints - "Character Received", on the serial monitor as expected. The TX of the adapter for XBEE 1 and the RX of the adapter for XBEE 2 also blinks at the same moment, confirming that the character is being sent by the XBEE 1 and it is being received by XBEE 2 for the Arduino to print.

**The Problem:**
Now, I uploaded the following sketch to do the reverse job, so that XBEE 2 sends the data and it appears on the XCTU console of XBEE 1:

```
#include<HardwareSerial.h>
UART mySerial(digitalPinToPinName(4), digitalPinToPinName(3), NC, NC);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  mySerial.print("a");
  delay(1000);
}
```

This sketch does not print anything on the XCTU console of XBEE 1. I checked the connections and re-uploaded the sketch but it still showed nothing. I included the printing line inside a while-loop,

```
while(Serial.available()){
   mySerial.print("a");
}
```

so that I can manually type in a character into the serial monitor using Arduino IDE, but that also did not work. I also noticed that the respective TX and RX of the adapters also did not blink, meaning that XBEE 2 is not able to transmit the character only.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and I spent hours to resolve this issue. I also tried changing the Din and Dout pins of XBEE 2 to RX and TX pins of the Arduino but that also did not work, although I think that's because the RX and TX are already being used by the Serial Connection between Arduino and laptop.

Any help to point me into the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

*Some points*:
I came to know that SoftwareSerial library isn't available for the version of Arduino that I am using and for this reason I am using the UART instruction:
`UART mySerial(digitalPinToPinName(4), digitalPinToPinName(3), NC, NC);`
based on the discussion [in this forum](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos/issues/38). I also use CP2012 XBEE explorer as adapters for XBEES.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142531/discussion-on-question-by-rayford03-arduino-nano-ble-33-sense-receives-but-not-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.